# What statistical tools would you use for identifiying important factors/variables in an experiment?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I conducted a experiment where I measured bacteria on a 1000 peoples' hands after performing a repeatable task.

[image]

This scatter graph shows 2 experiments where the humidity of the hands is changed.
 I then repeated the experiment under 4 different conditions. What would you use to work out whether a variable was statistically important in alterring the results?
EDIT:
The experiment is actually numerical in nature:
The black points are produced by a function:

$$Y=f(A,V,\lambda)=\sum_{i=1}^nA_iV_i\lambda_i$$

Where $A$ $V$ and $\lambda$ are drawn from empirical distributions

the red points conform to:
$$Y=g(A,V,\lambda,\beta)=\sum_{j=0}^i \left(\prod_{k=j+1}^i \beta_k\sigma_j\right)$$

where $\sigma=A\lambda V$ and $\beta$ is an empirical distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first be looking at fitting [a generalized linear model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) accounting for the various independent variables in the model; the test would correspond to testing whether one (or perhaps several) coefficients in a model were significantly different from zero.

Comment: And would this tell me to what extent one variable was more important than another? Ie I was thinking about PCA. Also as it happens I know the red dots behave non-linearly whereas the black ones behave linearly. Does knowing this information change anything? Regards,

Comment: It depends on what your criterion for importance is as to whether it's directly available or you need to do further calculation. Knowing there's a nonlinear effect would impact how you model it. In the case of GLMs that might either cause you to consider a different link function, or to look at how to model the curve (which might depend on what you know or expect about it) - GAMs might be used if you don't know its form.

Comment: Ah interesting. The reason we know the red points are non-linear in nature is because this experiment is actually a simulation and I know the function which generated both red and black. What I'm looking for is a way to distinguish whether one parameter affects the results more than another and to quantify this. Is it possible?

Comment: Added equations to questions

Comment: "*What I'm looking for is a way to distinguish whether one parameter affects the results more than another and to quantify this*". More details would help, but there would usually be several ways to do something like that... but without details it's a little hard to be precise. What 'one factor' and 'other factor'? And do you mean under the red or the black situation?